# WSAPI error when running cgilua.fcgi

Tags: lua, lighttpd, wsapi

I'm trying to configure a webserver to use **Lua** to create web applications.
I use **lighttpd** as my default webserver to run *static websites* and *PHP blogs*, so, my obvious choice was lighttpd.

Searching in Google and in this list history, I see that would be easy to configure, in fast steps, that I follow:

- Install cgilua with luarocks
- Install wsapi and wsapi-fcgi with luarocks as dependence
- Configure few lines in lighttpd.conf
- Restart lighttpd

When I did this, lighttpd stop to serve my websites.
Then I run cgilua.fcgi in terminal, and always I receive this error message:

> WSAPI error in application:
>   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/wsapi/common.lua:408: could not find a
>   filename to load, check your configuration or URL stack traceback:
>     [C]: in function 'error'
>     /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/wsapi/common.lua:408: in function
>   'adjust_non_wrapped'  /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/wsapi/common.lua:422:
>   in function 'normalize_paths'
>     /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/wsapi/common.lua:665: in function
>      (tail call): ?  [C]:
>   in function 'xpcall'  /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/wsapi/common.lua:257:
>   in function 'run_app'     /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/wsapi/common.lua:284:
>   in function 'run'     /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/wsapi/fastcgi.lua:40: in
>   function 'run'
>     ...al/lib/luarocks/rocks/cgilua/5.1.4-1/bin/cgilua.fcgi:33: in main
>   chunk     [C]: ?

Anybody can help me? What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I found was use simple cgi configuration on lighttpd.
No cgilua, no fastcgi, no dependencies, just enabled cgi module in lighttpd and added:

```
cgi.assign = (
    ".lua"  => "/usr/bin/lua",
)
```

But I've been read that cgi is too slow, and FastCGI is better.
"Pure cgi" is too bad to use? I think so simple and fast to configure that I'm thinking use this approach to start my web application.

Any suggestions?